# Translate Plone Subjects/Keywords

Tags: plone

Is there a way to translate Plone Subjects/Keywords?

I already tried .po translations, but this does not work?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to translate the *content* of the fields or the *labels*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use translations in a .po file (use the "plone" domain) but you need to customize all templates that display keywords (view, edit, ...) wrapping the raw text rendering into a `i18n:translate=""` TALES expression.

For exampple, for the display you need to customize this:
https://github.com/plone/plone.app.layout/blob/da9d5077668d3bab502ea0f585fdae5c753956f0/plone/app/layout/viewlets/keywords.pt#L15

You can probably perform a lot of this stuff simply using z3c.jbot.

Comment: Thank you, plone domain was it ;-)